# Uniqueness of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to show that the ivp $x'=\max\{1,x\},x(0)=1$ has a unique solution defined for all t and then find it.

Im wondering if my approach to the problem is correct:

I need to show that $f(t,x)=\max\{1,x\}=\begin{cases} 1 &x\leq 1 \\ x & x>1 \end{cases}$

has a continous and bounded partial derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$.

$$\frac{\partial f(t,x)}{\partial x}=\begin{cases} 0&x\leq 1 \\ 1& x>1 \end{cases}$$

Which exists and is continous for every pair $(t_0,x_0)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}$, and we have that $(0,1)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}$.

It is also bounded $\left|\frac{\partial f(t,x)}{\partial x}\right|=\begin{cases} 0\leq K&x\leq 1 \\ 1\leq K& x>1 \end{cases} $

For $K\geq 0$ and for all $(t_0,x_0)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$. Therefore the Cauchy problem $x'=\max\{1,x\},x(0)=1$ has a unique solution defined for all t.

To find the solution: $x'(t)=\begin{cases}1 &x\leq 1 \\ x & x>1 \end{cases} \Rightarrow x(t)=\begin{cases} t+C_1 &x\leq 1 \\ tx+C_2 &x>1 \end{cases}$

$x(0)=1 \Rightarrow x(t)=\begin{cases} t+1 &x\leq 1 \\ tx+1 &x>1 \end{cases} $

Did I mess something up or does it look fine?

Comment: Think again about the solution to $\dot x=x$. $x$ is not a constant.

Comment: $x'(t)=x$ and then we integrate both sides with respect to $t$? Isn't the integration with respect to $t$?

Comment: Write it out completely, $x(t)-x(0)=\int_0^tx(s)\,ds$ where the unknown function $x$ is now in the integrand helping nothing. Separation of variables works, but one should be able to identify the ODE of the exponential function at a glance.

Comment: Ok fair enough, but doesn't $x(t)=tx+C$ also satisfy $x'(t)=x$. Im curious on why it does not work using this function as solution?

Comment: No, by the product rule the derivative of this equation is $\dot x=t\dot x+x$.

Comment: How is that possible, is $x(t)$ a function of both $t$ and $x$?

Comment: You seem to work under the expression that $x$ and $x(t)$ are different separate thing in the ODE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $f$ is not differentiable at $x=1$. As you already pointed out, the derivative would jump, and this is impossible for differentiable functions (see  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis) )
You can repair this point, by proving Lipschitz continuity instead (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity)

Another point was mentioned by LutzL. I repeat it here. The solution for $\dot{x}=x$ is not correct. In general the solution is only dependent on $t$, not on $x$. Here it would be $x(t)=c\cdot e^t$ with $c$ an arbitrary constant.

Comment: So to show that the Cauchy problem is unique, one can use either methods? But where does one apply the initial value $x(t_0)=x_0$ in the Lipschitz continuity argument?

Comment: In this case, you don't need to apply the initial value anywhere, since your $f$ is globally Lipschitz. In general it may happen, that a function is not locally Lipschitz everywhere, but on parts of its domain (for example $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$) In these cases, you have to make sure, that your inital value lies outside these bad points and the solutions stays outside. To either method: What you need for Uniqueness and Existence is for $f$ to satisfy a local Lipschitz condition in $x$. If $f$ is differentiable in $x$, then it is locally Lipschitz as well.

Comment: Ok, is this correct application of Lipschitz continuity:

$$|f(x)-f(y)|=\begin{cases} 0 & x,y\leq 1 \\ |x-y| & x,y,>1 \end{cases}$$. Therefore $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq L|x-y|$, where $L=0$ works in the first case and $L=1$ works in the second case. 

And the solutions are $x(t)=\begin{cases} t+1 & x\leq 1 \\ e^{t} &x>1 \end{cases}$.

Comment: For the Lipschitz continuity: What if $x\leq 1$ and $y>1$? Another point: The way you write down your solution can still be improved. Try to get rid of $x$ on the right hand side of your equation entirely. That means no $x>1$ in the distinction of cases. Try to express it in terms of $t$ instead. Luckily all solutions are monotonically increasing, so that should be doable.

Comment: If $x\leq 1$ and $y>1$, then $|f(x)-f(y)|=|1-y| \leq |x-y|$ where the last inequality follows since $x\leq 1$. Therefore $L=1$ works? 

I dont really understand the last part, how can I get rid of $x$ in the solution?

Comment: Your solution looks basically like this $x(t)=t+1$, if $x\leq1$. Try to get ridd of this $x\leq 1$ by expressing this condition only in terms of $t$.